# AngularJS $http redirect on status code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise, angular-http

I have a angular application with many `$http` request and i want redirect the users on the login page if the server session expires (get 401). Does anyone know a solution witch works for all `$http` without adding `.error()` on every `$http`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better if you could use an http interceptor to redirect all detected 401 errors.

```
// add an http interceptor via app.config
app.config(function($$httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('my401Detector');
});

// interceptor logic.
app.factory('my401Detector', function($location, $q) {
    return {
        responseError: function(response) {
            if(response.status === 401) {
                 $location.path('/login');
                 return $q.reject(response);
            }
            else {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Does this really work? It doesn't seem to actually perform a full page refresh. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location also states: "It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, `$window.location.href`."

Answer (score 2):

You can use Interceptors to achieve this. From Mean.js source code

```
angular.module('users').config(['$httpProvider',
function($httpProvider) {
    // Set the httpProvider "not authorized" interceptor
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', 'Authentication',
        function($q, $location, Authentication) {
            return {
                responseError: function(rejection) {
                    switch (rejection.status) {
                        case 401:
                            // Deauthenticate the global user
                            Authentication.user = null;

                            // Redirect to signin page
                            $location.path('signin');
                            break;
                        case 403:
                            // Add unauthorized behaviour 
                            break;
                    }

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
}
 ]);
```